# Accessing my Angular app from external system (proxy)

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I have an Angular frontend app.

There is a 3rd party would like to access my frontend & would like to see a specific view (the `products` view). The simply flow on this requirement would be this:
[image]

But the 3rd party proxy has following requirements to me:

1. They want to send a custom URL which my Angular app doesn't understand. Let's say their custom URL is `http://foo.bar`.
2. They want to send sensitive data along with the initial request.

So, I planned the following:

1. Their initial request is sent to my backend instead of my Angular frontend, so that I can translate their custom URL (`http://foo.bar`) to the one my Angular app can understand (`GET /products`). Besides, I can introduce some security check in the backend.
2. Asking 3rd party proxy to send a `POST` request instead of `GET`, so that the sensitive data is in a payload.

So, my plan is like this:
[image]

But I have the following questions:

1. Do I understand correctly that in general, when user enters URL on browser for an Angular application, the browser will load the whole Angular application to the browser? And after that, the routing rule in Angular takes effect to decide which view to render?
2. If above answer is YES, then, do I see correctly that my above plan wouldn't work for showing the `products` view to 3rd party unless I also ask the 3rd party proxy to do a URL mapping configuration, otherwise the responsed Angular app(step `3` & `4` in above diagram) doesn't know how to show the `products` view since the URL is `http://foo.bar` on 3rd party side?

Answer (score 0):

Creating additional Backend will increase the complexity of the solution, although required result can be achieve using this approach.
If 3rd party would only like to access your frontend & would like to see a specific view then the simple solution is `Use an IFrame`. 
To use an iframe, follow these steps:

- Generate an iframe code in your Angular application that includes the URL of your ProductsComponent route. For example: 
  `<iframe src="https://your-app-domain/products" width="100%" height="500"></iframe>`
- Provide the generated iframe code to the third-party application.
- The third-party application can then embed this iframe code within
  their HTML, and it will display your **ProductsComponent** within the
  iframe.

`Note:`
 Please keep in mind that using an iframe can have    limitations, such as potential styling conflicts or security    considerations. Also, the embedded component won't have direct access    to the third-party application's JavaScript or DOM, and communication    between the iframe and the parent application may require additional    techniques.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question nr. 1 is yes (mostly):

An angular application will trigger a reload of the complete code to bootstrap your application. Depending if you're using lazy loading or not, some parts of your application will be loaded on-demand. For example, let's say you setup `/bar` as a lazy module, then only when the user activates that route the application will request another javascript-chunk with the missing components for `bar`.

Regarding question Nr. 2, there are many unanswered aspects, like what the backend looks like, but I think that what you were thinking of should work. I'm figuring something like this:

Assuming you have configured your webserver (e.g. nginx) to redirect the POST `https://external.url` to `https://internal.app`. Then, your backend would get the POST headers unchanged. Your backend-application could then process the POST arguments and then redirect the response to the angular-app with some GET arguments in order to configure the view. E.g. redirect to `https://angular-app/products?filter=123`, or if that's not that suitable for your needs, there's also the possibility to make the backend render the view server-side and then send it as a response. But I think this only works with `nodejs` as a backend and I have no experience with that, so I'm not sure if that's the best alternative.